# How can I set up a supervisor to multiple workers in multiple tasks in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I have 4 tasks, and I have assigned 2 workers to each task. As these tasks will be done at the same time, and are correlated, I want to assign a supervisor to these 8 workers.

So, basically this supervisor will guide all the 8 workers in the same area. How do I enter such a supervisor in MS Project 2016 for these 4 tasks?

Comment: MS project assists you to create and maintaining schedule; why do you need to embed organizational supervision in a schedule maintenance tool?

Comment: Are you trying to merely record the supervisor's name against each task so there is a record of it, or are you trying to create an actual resource for the Supervisor and allocate them onto the tasks? I am voting to close the question as Unclear until/unless this is clarified.

Comment: I expect the supervisor to solve the issues workers face in their work.

Some workers will do electrical fitting, some will put up security installations in the building, while others store and bring material from store room. These are different activities assigned to different workers. A single supervisor will put in his hours helping workers.

So, while each worker is puts in 8 hours of work to one activity, the supervisor engineer is putting in 8 hours of cumulative work to all the above mentioned activities. 

How do I log these supervisor's hours and assignment to tasks.

Comment: Use timekeeping tools to log hours; use planning tools to plan.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to go to your Resource Sheet >> insert the Phonetics column >> type in the supervisor name for each resource.

Go to the Task Sheet view >> insert the Resource Phonetics column.

Now, whenever the resource is assigned to the task, the supervisor(s) will show up in the Resource Phonetics column.

To make it obvious what this column really is in the Task Sheet view, right click on Resource Phonetics >> Field Settings >> set the title to Resource Supervisors.

If this doesn't get you what you're looking for, tell me what your goal is.